# Should node-gyp be installed globally and locally?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I am looking at nodejs addon examples at https://github.com/nodejs/abi-stable-node-addon-examples.

The read-me section says that I must install node-gyp globally:

```
$ sudo npm install node-gyp -g
```

However, after installing node-gyp globally, does one also need to install it within the local project?

```
$ cd myproject
$ npm install node-gyp
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is good to install the **node-gyp** globally because main purpose of the **node-gyp** is to build the **node native modules**. **node-gyp** also need some tool like *visual studio* (in case of building on Windows)
and **python** which also installed globally.

after install globally no need to install it locally.